# module_platform_driver order and mounting rootf

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver

I am working on some embedded Linux system and I'm trying to run Linux from USB pendrive. I put "root=/dev/sda3 rootwait" to commandline parameters of the Linux but it doesn't recognize the USB at all when it should mount /dev/sda3. 
When I try to run from /dev/mmcblk0p2 everything is ok - Linux kernel recognizes this device BEFORE mounting the rootfs. The problem is only when I try to mount USB as a rootfs.

The USB is recognized only when I run the system from initramfs, but it recognized AFTER the rootfs is mounted.

My question is: how can I move initiation of USB subsystem before mounting rootfs?

Comment: It may be that USB is not enumerated by the time rfs mounting starts, Add "rootdelay=60" and see if it helps in booting from USB device?

Comment: Is */dev/sda* a USB stick? You need to compile all necessary drivers into the kernel. Otherwise you have to use an intermediate initramfs (usual way).

Comment: Yes, /dev/sda is a USB stick. Actually the issue is fixed. I was testing by mistake the wrong kernel (without built-in usb host and usb storage drivers). After I run the proper kernel everything started and now it is working fine.